# What does Microsoft Active Protection Service (formerly SpyNet) actually upload?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I would like to see an example of data that is uploaded by the "Cloud-delivered protection" (MAPS) in Windows Defender on Windows 10.

**What steps do i need to take on my Windows machine to review some (any past or future) upload Microsoft is referring to in the following quote?**

> This information can include things like location of detected items on
>   your computer if harmful software was removed. The information will be
>   automatically collected and sent.
>
> `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Windows Components > Windows Defender Antivirus > MAPS`

I have a Windows 10 PC with MAPS enabled & automatic sample submission disabled. I am interested in what information MAPS submits in my installation, not what might be sent if i had *`Send file samples when further analysis is required`* enabled.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Windows automatically uploads some suspicious-looking files and reports data about suspicious activity so new threats can be detected and blocked as quickly as possible.

This feature won’t just haphazardly upload files from your system to Microsoft’s servers. It will only upload .exe and other program files. It won’t upload your personal documents and other files that could contain personal data.
Using the cloud-based protection feature, Windows Defender can send information to Microsoft’s servers (“the cloud”) whenever suspicious-looking events occur. Rather than making the decision ultimately with the information available on your PC, the choice is produced on Microsoft’s servers with the usage of the latest malware information available from Microsoft’s research time, machine-learning reasoning, and massive amounts of up-to-date raw data.

There’s also a “Submit a sample manually” link here, which takes you to the Submit a file for malware analysis page on Microsoft’s website. You can manually upload a suspicious file here.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission

Comment: Thanks, that answers a different question though. I have edited my question to clarify.